Does DOS require partitions to be aligned at a cylinder boundary?
Large Disk HOWTO §6.2 claims that MS-DOS 6.22 requires extended partitions to be aligned to a cylinder boundary.
On the other hand, another article I found claims that any alignment requirement is a misconception and MS-DOS never requires partitions to be aligned to any boundary.
Which is right?  Does DOS require partitions to be cylinder-aligned or not?

Welcome to the club! I had discovered about two years ago this is a myth that descends from the DOS era to present. The Large Disk HOWTO is correct.

The Large Disk HOWTO is correct.  MS-DOS requires CHS EBRs (type ID 5) – but only CHS EBRs – to be cylinder-aligned.
This can be discovered by studying internal DOS data structures, especially the one Ralf Brown’s calls the “Drive Data Table”, but MS-DOS itself calls the “BDS”.0  The DOS kernel creates one BDS entry for each discovered partition; each contains a BIOS Parameter Block, which in turn contains the “hidden sectors” field storing the partition offset.  MS-DOS takes this value directly from the LBA offset field of the partition table entry.1  When accessing a partition, MS-DOS internally uses linear addressing: the “hidden sectors” value is added to a linear sector number relative to the start of the file system and then the result is converted into CHS coordinates in order to invoke ROM disk services.
For extended partitions, the LBA offset in the partition table, and therefore the internal “hidden sectors” value is relative to the containing Extended Boot Record.  To locate the partition correctly, the DOS kernel also remembers the cylinder number of the EBR (in a field otherwise used for the last access time of floppy drives, offset +0x49 in the MS-DOS 4.0–7.0 kernel), and offsets the cylinder coordinate by this value when accessing the partition.  So if the EBR is not located on head 0 sector 1, the computed sector coordinate will be wrong.  The partition itself, though, can otherwise be at any offset; Microsoft FDISK will put it on the next track after the EBR, but this is not required.
This limitation only applies to “CHS” (type ID 5) extended partitions on MS-DOS.  “LBA” extended partitions (type ID 0x0F), as supported by MS-DOS 7.x and 8.x, are not subject to it; when enumerating those, the kernel computes the absolute partition offset and stores it in the “hidden sectors” field, while the EBR cylinder is ignored (the field is set to zero, like for primary partitions).
Other DOS kernels need not be affected either; DR DOS, for example, computes the “hidden sectors” value from the CHS coordinates of the first sector (which are not EBR-relative for extended partitions) instead of copying the LBA offset field, while FreeDOS computes a separate absolute disk offset and tacks it onto an extra field at the end of the Drive Data Table/BDS.

0 I could find no expansion of the acronym within the published source code; one could guess it stands for something like “BIOS Drive Structure”.  OpenDOS/DR DOS calls the same structure the “unit descriptor”.  FreeDOS, however, does actually call it the Drive Data Table, as they basically cribbed all DOS APIs directly from the RBIL, where it was given that name.
1 The others are also determined by the DOS kernel on its own.  Which is to say, the BPB stored in the BDS is not a copy of the BPB stored on-disk; it’s the other way around, FORMAT writes this BPB to the partition boot sector when creating the file system.  FreeDOS gets this backwards!

Excellent answer. In my fork of MS-DOS v4 I added LBA support (like MS-DOS v7) and went the (E)DR-DOS way to always store the full hidden sectors (absolute in the int 13h unit) in the hidden sectors field, avoiding the cylinder boundary need. I also was unable to determine what BDS means albeit I did find "BDSM" used, ie "BDS structure for mini disk". The hidden sectors question, and thus the need for cylinder boundaries, was also discussed on the SvarDOS EDR-DOS tracker.

@ecm https://github.com/AR1972/DOS3.3/blob/50868cd2d277149c3733f051facfa3c67568700c/AG.DOC#L4115

The “DDT” in FreeDOS is such a mess: https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/bugs/277/.

Also, I almost included a paragraph about QEMU relying on partitions being cylinder-aligned for automatic geometry determination from the MBR partition table, but then decided against it. Perhaps I will write about it in a different question.

OTOH I think the FreeDOS (with FAT32) kernel's SFT likely matches MS-DOS v7.10's exactly, depicting why MS-DOS v6.22/v7.00 share.exe won't work on v7.10. They re-used parts of the IFS pointer and "share next SFT pointer" to hold parts of FAT32 cluster numbers, to avoid increasing the size of an SFT entry. EDR-DOS went with a cleaner design in which the SFT entries grew to accommodate the FAT32 extensions (and also the FAT+ extensions to file size and current file seek).

Ah, Block Data Structure. Now tell me, what does nibdos mean? It just includes msconst.nas which contains the jump to msdos init (section START) and the start of the DOS data segment (section CONSTANTS), that is the List of Lists (int 21.52 data) and the sharer jump table.

By the time of DOS 6.2, most hard disks were LBA as far as I remember. That probably affects the answer.

@ecm: DOS BDSM?  I've always considered using DOS to be a form of torture, but not the fun kind.  But I'm not going to kink-shame anyone for their hobbies, retrocomputing or otherwise. :P

@PeterCordes I just abolished the end of BDSM as part of my MS-DOS kernel fork. I'll probably write about it some on my blog within the next two weeks.
